# AttributeError : module 'word2number' has no attribute 'word_to_num'

Tags: attributes

The code I'm working on is with a dataset which contains like numbers in alphabets, So I want to convert it into string to feed to into a Multivariate Model.
!pip install word2number
import pandas as pd
import math
from sklearn import linear_model
import word2number as w2n

```
print("sucessfully imported all the libraries")

df = pd.read_csv('hiring.csv')
df

print(w2n.word_to_num('one'))
```

This is my code and the error I'm getting is

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\Users\tanus\Desktop\Machine Learning\Regression\Multivariate Regression\Multivariate_Regression.ipynb Cell 2 in <cell line: 4>()
      1 df = pd.read_csv('hiring.csv')
      2 df
----> 4 print(w2n.word_to_num('one'))

AttributeError: module 'word2number' has no attribute 'word_to_num'
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to import w2n module from word2number

```
from word2number import w2n
print(w2n.word_to_num('two point three'))
```

You are directly using `word_to_num` from the module i assume.

Please check the import statement.
The error is possible if you use below import.

```
import word2number as w2n
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I've imported the module in another cell because I use a Python Notebook.

Answer (score 0):

```
from word2number import w2n

w2n.word_to_num('two hundred and one')

#201
```

It is **not** importing the library "**as**" w2n,

w2n is a **module** inside the word2number library, good luck